# JQuery - work with divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set another class for the clicked menu-part. Clicking generates url with #NAME. Here is my menu:

```
    <div id="head_menu">
        <a href="#order"><div name="order" id="menu_part">make order</div></a>
        <a href="#portfolio"><div id="menu_part">portfolio</div></a>
        <a href="#contacts"><div id="menu_part">contacts</div></a>
        <a href="#vacancies"><div id="menu_part">vacancies</div></a>
        <a href="#about"><div id="menu_part">about company</div></a>
    </div>
```

I need to add class: 'menu_choosed' for clicked part. Here is my jquery-code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        currentPage = window.location.hash;
        $('#head_menu>div').each(
            function()
            {
                if( currentPage == $(this).hash )
                {
                    $(this).addClass("menu_choosed");
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

I really don't know, how to filter values :( Help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        currentPage = window.location.hash;

        $('#head_menu a[href=' + currentPage + '] div').addClass('menu_choosed');
    }
);
```

There are a few problems with your HTML I would like to mention:

- Nowadays, most people use lists (`<ul>`, mostly) for navigation.
- Having a `<div>` inside an `<a>` is invalid if the `<div>` has `display: block` (default) and the `<a>` has `display: inline` (default).
- One document may only have one element per ID.  You currently have several elements with the `menu_part` id.
- Using `name` for anchor points is not recommended.  Prefer using ID's.

Comment: @Ockonal, Try removing the `div` part from the selector.  It isn't clear if you want to add the class to the `div` or the `a`.

Comment: Doesn't help. Okay, I'll rework my menu-structure. Thanks, I understood what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

All IDs must be unique. You're currently repeating menu_part. I'd suggest removing the duplicate IDs. Give the nav links a class of "nav_link" and then use jquery to reference that class with an onclick event that changes the class to "menu_choosed".

Comment: And if 'menu_part' is a stylesheet for my divs?

Comment: then change it to a class. see my answer

Comment: If this was a comment, I would upvote it.  This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        var currentPage = window.location.hash;
        $('#head_menu a div').each(
            function()
            {
                if( currentPage == $(this).parent().attr("href") )
                {
                    $(this).addClass("menu_choosed");
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be  $('#head_menu>a>div') I believe.
also, ids are supposed to be unique, so it could cause problems that you have multiple divs with the same id. you may want to change menu_part to a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#head_menu").find("a[href=" + window.location.hash + "]").addClass('highlight')
```